Go server running in a docker container , having trouble with kafka client library
I am running a go server inside a docker container, here is the docker file
# Use the official Go image as the base image
FROM golang:latest

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /go/src/GoBackend

# Copy your Go code into the container's working directory
COPY . .
RUN go mod download
# Define the entry point command
CMD ["go","run","/go/src/GoBackend/main.go"]


main.go file  imports the  kafka client library "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"
Container builds fine without any errors, but when i run the container it gives the following errors:
gobackend-1         | # command-line-arguments
gobackend-1         | /usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_arm64/link: running gcc failed: exit status 1
gobackend-1         | /usr/bin/ld: /go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go@v1.9.2/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_glibc_linux.a(rdkafka_error.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
gobackend-1         | /usr/bin/ld: /go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go@v1.9.2/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_glibc_linux.a(rdkafka_error.o): Relocations in generic ELF (EM: 62)
gobackend-1         | /usr/bin/ld: /go/pkg/mod/github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go@v1.9.2/kafka/librdkafka_vendor/librdkafka_glibc_linux.a: error adding symbols: file in wrong format
gobackend-1         | collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gobackend-1         |
gobackend-1 exited with code 1
Chat gpt suggested modifying the docker file to build in two stages which is as follow,
Build Stage (builder):
We use the official Go image.
Set environment variables CGO_ENABLED=1, GOOS=linux, and GOARCH=arm64 to ensure the Go application is built with CGO enabled and for the correct architecture.
Set the working directory and copy go.mod and go.sum files first to leverage Docker layer caching.
Download the Go modules.
Copy the rest of the Go code and build the application.
Final Stage:
We use the alpine:latest image to create a smaller final image.
Install CA certificates required by many Go applications.
Set the working directory.
Copy the built Go application from the builder stage.
Expose port 8080.
Define the entry point command to run the built Go application.
and here is the new suggested docker file with the above mentioned suggestions configured:
# Use the official Go image as the base image
FROM golang:latest AS builder

# Set environment variables for the build
ENV CGO_ENABLED=1
ENV GOOS=linux
ENV GOARCH=arm64

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /go/src/GoBackend

# Copy go.mod and go.sum to download dependencies first
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download

# Copy the rest of your Go code into the container's working directory
COPY . .

# Build the Go application
RUN go build -o main .

# Use a smaller base image for the final container
FROM alpine:latest

# Install CA certificates
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates

# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /root/

# Copy the built Go application from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /go/src/GoBackend/main .

# Expose the port your application runs on
EXPOSE 8080

# Define the entry point command
CMD ["./main"]


but this led to some other errors, which I couldn't figure out because of my lack of expertise in building go programs and working with kafka in general.
What is causing the issue?
What would be the right way to tackle this issue?

Mixing a Debian-based Go build stage and an Alpine-based runtime stage tends to not work well.  If you change the final stage to, say, FROM debian:bookworm, does it work better?

I tried what you suggested, and now I am getting the following error while building.
=> ERROR [gobackend stage-1 2/4] RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates                                                                                                                        0.2s
=> CANCELED [gobackend builder 6/6] RUN go build -o main .                                                                                                                                     0.2s

[gobackend stage-1 2/4] RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates:
0.185 /bin/sh: 1: apk: not found

